# Reading JSON file with a filestream

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Using the NodeJS `fs` module, what is the best way to read a JSON file using a filestream. While many solutions work for files that have linebreaks, the JSON files I need to work with are written to by the NodeJS process and thus are all on one line.

The file in question needs to be read and parsed into a usable Javascipt object with `JSON.parse()` however, as it is an array of objects I thought that it might be possible to only read one object at a time and parse to check values. However I have no idea how to do this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if I were in the middle of this array during its process of being read, and needed to update the object that was currently being read, without disturbing its position in the array, would that be possible without having to read the entire file into memory?

Comment: Is it not feasible for you to wait until the entire file is read before 'consuming' the JSON ?

Comment: @LiamMacDonald The file in question could become very, very large over time and I want to ensure that the server is as memory efficient as possible

Comment: Do you have access to the NodeJS and JSON files? If so, you should consider using a database instead of JSON files, and convert each object of those huge JSON arrays as database records.

Comment: @Wikiti it was more of an experiment to see if this approach was possible, while a database would be more practical, I thought it would be interesting to see if it was possible with serialized data formats such as JSON or YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Product recommendations are out of scope for question on SO

2) "The file in question needs to be read and parsed into a usable Javascipt object with JSON.parse()" - since JSON.parse() doesn't do what you describe, what you are sking is impossible given this constraint.

JSON.parse() is a DOM parser - it treats the input as a complete datagram. There are event based parsers for JSON implemented in Javascript (e.g. [clarinet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clarinet)) often tagged as 'SAX' parsers (which actually refers to XML event based parsers).

> Also, if I were in the middle of this array during its process of being read, and needed to update the object that was currently being read, without disturbing its position in the array, would that be possible without having to read the entire file into memory?

Not without carrying the insert on the string representation of the JSON - which would be silly.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, and the level of detail :)

Answer (score -1):

**Sync**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('jsonfile', 'utf8'));
```

**Async**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var obj;
fs.readFile('jsonfile', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

According to your requirement you can use either way to read json

Comment: This loads the entire file into the memory of the server, and does not utilise filestreams. Loading the entire file into memory was what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @chkdrv whenever you ask a question if there is no code to explain, ask your question in point form which will be easy to read and answer, It's just my suggestion